# TYPO3 image crop disable this function

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 crops the media files which were added as text & media. How can I disable this? I want that it uses the original file.

It always takes this:

```
fileadmin/_processed_/c/a/csm_herren2_b3373d24a3.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the fluid template and remove the width and height attributes of the

Or maybe easier change the typoscript constant that define the max size to a higher value `styles.content.textmedia.maxW = 600` and `styles.content.textmedia.maxWInText = 300`.

Comment: I want a maxwidth of 100%

Comment: Then the easiest way is to adjust the template. To get the direct link to the image use `{file.publicUrl}`.